# adding a list to the function by index

Tags: python, list

I have a function which takes the list as an input. The list is as follows :

```
[ [ [179.0,77.0], [186.0,93.0], [165.0,91.0  ],..],
  [ [178.0,76.0 ],[185.0,93.0 ],[164.0,91.0 ] ,..],...]
```

I want to give this list by index so that the function will normalize(already written)  the data for each index and predict(already written the function logic) for each index. The example is as follows :

```
normalzed_list = normalize(list)
predict(normalized_list) # this function should predict based on the index of the list.
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: This is a list inside a list inside a list. So its unclear what you mean by "list by index" and which normalization function you want to apply.

Comment: I have already written normalize(). Consider the second inner list as the input .[ [179.0,77.0], [186.0,93.0], [165.0,91.0  ],...  ] as the input

Comment: I want to give the subsequent lists to the predict() and get the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `map()`

```
normalized = map(normalize, lst)
predicted = map(predict, normalized)

result = list(predicted)  # evaluate the generator
```

For debugging purposes you would want to put `list()` around the first `map()`.

Edit:
The index you can get by `enumerate()`.

```
predicted = map(lambda e: predict(e[0], e[1]), enumerate(normalized))
```

e[0] has the index, e[1] the normalized list.

Comment: I want to give this list by index so that the function will normalize(already written) the data for each index and give that output to predict() (already written the function logic) for each index.I have already written normalize(). Consider the second inner list as the input [ [179.0,77.0], [186.0,93.0], [165.0,91.0 ],... ]

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the index of the list element, can simply do this
`normalized_list = normalize(list[idx])`. Where idx is the known index.

Comment: I want to give this list by index so that the function will normalize(already written) the data for each index and give that output to predict() (already written the function logic) for each index.I have already written normalize(). Consider the second inner list as the input [ [179.0,77.0], [186.0,93.0], [165.0,91.0 ],... ]